# Proof of the Sum of Interior Angles of a Convex Polygon

Tags: geometry

Asked to prove the following theorem:

The sum of the interior angles of a convex polygon with n sides is $(n-2)π$ radians. Moreover if the polygon is regular the measure of each interior angle is $\dfrac{n-2}{n}π$.

Comment: ok, What did you do so far?

Comment: Hint: divide polygon into triangles by picking an interior point and connecting it to the vertices